# Real mode and loading linux kernel confusing

Tags: boot, grub, linux-kernel, x86

As far as I know, protected mode will be activated in kernel and in grub stages it still real mode. My misunderstanding is: In real mode, total memory available for use is less than 1MB but how grub can load the kernel and even root file system (usualy bigger than 1MB) to memory?

Answer (score 5):

GRUB does not have to load the whole kernel into memory. The kernel image is split into two pieces:

- The real-mode kernel code, which is small and can be loaded within the 640kB threshold of available memory;
- The rest of the kernel, which runs in protected mode and is loaded after the first megabyte of memory.

The bootloader only loads the real-mode kernel code, which in turn bootstraps the rest (take a look at `go_to_protected_mode()` in `arch/x86/boot/pm.c`). This is how the process can stay within the memory limitations of running in real mode.

A small note: GRUB may run in *both* real mode and protected mode, depending on what it is doing. It may switch into protected mode for some things (some hardware detection, and menu display). You are right, however, in thinking that it is in real mode when it hits the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! In Grub spec, it loads both kernel (may be only one piece :D) and root filesystem (mine is 32MiB). So, how about root filesystem?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên The kernel is the one dealing with the root filesystem, not GRUB.

Comment: I had that confused because this article: http://blog.adminnote.com/2010/10/linux-boot-process-step-by-step.html

Thanks for corrected me ;)

Comment: From what I read here (http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/x86/boot.txt) this is wrong. Of course, Grub can access the memory above 1 MiB and start the kernel in real mode nonetheless. Assuming that Grub does not have to load the complete kernel image and initrd makes little sense to me. That would mean that the kernel has to understand the `/boot` file system **before** it loads the initrd (and even most of itself!). You are familiar with the kernel unable to access the root device. Ever heard of a kernel unable to load the initrd? Please think about that again.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I can't quite understand what you're saying, but you will want to read section 16 [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html). GRUB *can* start the kernel in whatever mode it likes, that doesn't mean it should. The kernel does *not* have to understand `/boot` before it loads the initrd -- the initrd is provided to the kernel by the bootloader (and the bootloader handles the filesystem). Whether you find it makes "little sense" or not is irrelevant to its veracity. If you expect me to comment on some specific part of boot.txt, please provide the section.

Comment: I well remember the last time you didn't care about it that your answer made "little sense" to me. Grub loads the whole kernel image and initrd to memory. Most of it above 1 MiB, of course. You write both "GRUB does not have to load the whole kernel into memory" and "the initrd is provided to the kernel by the bootloader" which obviously contradicts each other. You simultaneously claim "The bootloader only loads the real-mode kernel code" and "GRUB can start in real mode, but it doesn't in Linux's case". If that makes sense to the other readers, well...

Comment: @HaukeLaging "Real mode" in the last example should be "protected mode". The whole kernel is not contained within the initrd. Take a look at `decompress_kernel()` and `start_kernel()` -- the kernel args are written by the bootloader and passed to the initrd for use.

Comment: So, After readed above comments, I am still confusing again. Is my under stand is right:
`1`. Grub load a part of kernel (below 1MiB - because grub in real-mode, can't access all memory).
`2`. Above loaded part of kenel continue load the complete kernel and initrd to memory
`3`. The boot process continue as ussualy

Is that right?

Comment: @ChrisDown: Please help me figure out the things :-(

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in real mode by means of BIOS int 0x15, 0x87 function. GDT must be filled appropriately for source and destination. `cx` - number of bytes to move.

```
    push edx
    push es
    xor  ax, ax
    mov  es, ax
    mov  ah, 0x87
    mov  si, gdt
    int  0x15
    jc   error
    pop  es
    pop  edx
    ret

gdt:
    times   16  db  0
    dw  0xffff              ; segment limit
.src:
    dw  0
    db  2
    db  0x93                ; data access rights
    dw  0
    dw  0xffff              ; segment limit
.dest:
    dw  0
    db  0x10                ; load protected-mode kernel to 100000h
    db  0x93                ; data access rights
    dw  0
    times   16  db  0

 error:
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Jakuje The question is at the top of the page, this is an answer.

Comment: sorry. I looked wrong into the review queue.